# How to consistently either always single- or multiline each import statement in PhpStorm for TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, phpstorm, config, webstorm

Given a multi-line import statement in PhpStorm / WebStorm for TypeScript:

```
import {
    CsvParseTransform,
    FileSink,
    FileSource,
    FtpSource,
} from "pipeline";
```

My autoformat converts it to a single-line:

```
import {CsvParseTransform, FileSink, FileSource, FtpSource,} from "pipeline";
```

Yet also I have seen it do the opposite in some cases. (I haven't found a pattern, I assume it has to do with length of the line. My assumption is that it only multi-lines beyond a threshold.)

I want the behavior to be consistent in order to reduce the git-diff noise in pull requests. In my case, I want it to *always* multi-line.

Where can I find and set that config in PhpStorm / WebStorm?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Please try:

**Settings | Editor | Code Style | TypeScript | Wrapping and Braces | ES6 import/export** option.

You can set it to: **Wrap always** to get your imports splitted to multiple lines always.

[image: Screenshot of the setting window for TypeScript | Wrapping and Braces | ES6 import/export]

Comment: The possible values are: `Do not wrap`, `Wrap if long`, `Chop down if long`, and `Wrap always`.